# How to show above referrals in referral system?

Tags: php, mysql, referrals

I'm having a problem to show users in my referral system.

If you look at table you'll notice `userid` '29' was `refered` by '28';
and '28' by '26';
also '26' by '10'

When user session '29' is active the page should display above users.
Hope you got the idea.

**Referal table:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<?php
$rs=mysql_query("select userid from referal where refereduserid='29'") or  die(mysql_error());
$exitloopcount=mysql_num_rows($rs);
$last=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
if ($exitloopcount>0) 
{
  for($i=0;$i<$exitloopcount;$i++)
  {
    $rs=mysql_query("select userid from referal where refereduserid='".$last[$i]."'");
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
      echo $data[$i];
    } 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the relationship a one-to-one map? E.g. will 29 be refered by more than one userid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be able to done by one single query (like Oracle's `CONNECT BY` clause), but I'm not familiar with MySQL, so I'm offering you the alternative solution, as you will be told "don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore" by someone here.

This solution uses [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` function collection.

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `userid` FROM `referal` WHERE `refereduserid`=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id); //here $id=29
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $row["userid"];
    $id=intval($row["userid"]);
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
}
```

**Edit**:

Explanation:

One thing about `MySQLi` and `PDO` is that they supports [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

As this is a chained relationship (and thankfully a one-to-one one), I can simply prepare one query:

```sql
SELECT `userid` FROM `referal` WHERE `refereduserid`=?
```

this query will be used to continuously fetched the "referrer".

Then we bind the "initiate" id, `29`, and executes the query.

While a "referrer" is found, echo it out (as demonstrated in your code), and then re-bind it to the prepared query, and executes it to find its "referrer". Continue this step.

Using the sample date in your question:

1. bind: 29 -> executes -> get: 28
2. bind: 28 -> executes -> get: 26
3. bind: 26 -> executes -> get: 10
4. bind: 10 -> executes -> no result

Comment: Dear Passerby, thanks a lot for your time. but i couldn't understand your code,

Comment: @user2091156 Edited answer with explanation. Hope it helps!